# Golang encoding/json marshall add null

Tags: json, go, encoding

Hi i am working with golang on encoding/json and it return the json error with null:

```
{"user_message":"Can't find any Query with those parameters","application_context":"GroupsRepository.GetGroupsByQuery: ApplicationError: UserMessage - Error querying database for many Groups. ApplicationContext - Groups.GetMany: pq: column \"refill_too_soon_gpi_digits\" does not exist"} null
```

and the way that i marshall that it is:

```
func EncodeErrorResponse(w http.ResponseWriter, err error, status int) {
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(err)
}
```

could someone help me please.

Comment: Looking at the JSON output you quoted, it looks like the error is being encoded correctly, but `null` is being output *after* the JSON, indicating a separate write operation. Is it possible some other code (perhaps the caller of this function) is writing this output? Also note that you take in a status code but you don't use it, you always use StatusOK; and that you're ignoring the error returned by `Encode`.

Comment: The function i use in another function, but the error that the encode return is null, i don't know if encoding/json has problems, because with another struct it works fine.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with encoding/json. The function that calls `EncodeErrorResponse`, after it calls it, is writing additional output to the `ResponseWriter`.

Comment: Yes it was a error on the code, after it write the error i write a null value, thanks

Comment: Great! Reposted as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the JSON output you quoted, it looks like the error is being encoded correctly, but null is being output after the JSON, indicating a separate write operation. The function that calls EncodeErrorResponse, after it calls it, is writing additional output to the ResponseWriter.